# Line breaks in part of the equation in math mode - how to?

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

Does anybody know how to do this:

[image: line breaks in sections of an equation]

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use parboxes (change the width parameters in the following as appropriate).

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[                                                                              
\parbox{0.2\textwidth}{\centering Node power consumption}                       
+                                                                               
\parbox{0.2\textwidth}{\centering dynamic consumption}                          
+                                                                               
\parbox{0.2\textwidth}{\centering static consumption}                           
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: parboxes]

Comment: Awesome, that worked nicely. How can I get the math font though, so that all the formulas have the same look?

Comment: @shailenTJ --- By default the fonts in math mode and text mode are the same. Have you changed this in your document?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that uses just the basic `tabular` environment. By "wrapping" the `tabular`s in `\textit` directives you can typeset the letters in italics.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tabular}{c}
Node\\ power\\ consumption
\end{tabular}
=
\begin{tabular}{c}
dynamic\\ consumption
\end{tabular}
+
\begin{tabular}{c}
static\\ consumption
\end{tabular}
\]

\[
\textit{\begin{tabular}{c} 
Node\\ power\\ consumption
\end{tabular}}
=
\textit{\begin{tabular}{c}
dynamic\\ consumption
\end{tabular}}
+
\textit{\begin{tabular}{c}
static\\ consumption
\end{tabular}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `stackengine` package helps doing that without having to compute whatever with the `Centerstack` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\\}

\begin{document}
\[
\Centerstack{Node power\\consumption}
 =
\Centerstack{dynamic\\consumption}
+
\Centerstack{static\\consumption}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution using `tikz` package with math fonts also:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\sffamily
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=.5ex,every node/.style={align=center}]
\node (con) at (0,0) {Node\\power\\consumption};
\node (eq) [right=of con]{$=$};
\node (dy) [right=of eq]{dynamic\\consumption};
\node (pl) [right=of dy]{$+$};
\node (st) [right=of pl]{static\\consumption};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output is as follows:

[image]